# ASP.NET Web API datetime binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, data-binding, binding, asp.net-apicontroller

I submit JSON object, with date value "02/11/2015" (DD/MM/YYYY) to API controller. For some reason it gets converted into US format while binding (11th of Feb). I have standard MVC controllers in the same solution, which bind date value submitted in the same format correctly (UK). What would be causing this difference:

Here are standard MVC submission headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pl;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

And Form Data

```
StartDate : 01/11/2015
```

Here Are API call headers

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pl;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

And JSON object that I pass

```
{ DateStart: "01/11/2015" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the default dateFormat in webapi json serializer is not the same as MVC's one.

Try to specify in your WebApi in the config file (App_start/WebApiConfig).

Example:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
```

Or
       GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd"

with the DateFormat, DateZone you need.

More infos here:

[Post dates web api custom format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001405/post-dates-web-api-custom-format)

Comment: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd"` in the register method of your webapiconfig file does not change the format?

Comment: Made it work finally using custom converter for DateTime type: config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Insert(0, new MyDateTimeConverter()); Thanks for your help

Comment: Complete solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577796/net-webapi-1-datetime-converter